# How manipulate and use npm init & package.json

Tags: angularjs, npm, package.json

I have a new project with **AngularJS**, I clone an existing project whitin the principal **branch master** `(master -> origin) (essential-react@0.3.0)`. I run `npm init` and I have the package.json file. After that, I have some warnings when I type `npm audit`which I fixed with `npm i --package-lock-only`.

A new file `package-lock.json` was generated. Can any one gives me more details about the utility of this file, please. 
And more explanations about `npm init` and `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm init` is used to set up a new or existing npm package. So why does this matter to you? Well, since you're creating a new Angular project utilizing various `npm` libraries, you will need a **`package.json` file to manage said dependencies**. So `npm init` is assisting you by creating a new `package.json` file within your current directory. Now with that being said, what's the purpose of this `package.json` file? Well a `package.json` file *contains important metadata about your project*, such as the name of your project, version, and a list of packages your project depends on. This is important because it makes the **building of your project reproducible, and therefore easier to share with other developers.** So if later on you shared your new Angular project on GitHub someone could build your project on their end by downloading the required dependencies listed within your package.json. (**Note:** this is exactly what you did when you ran: `npm i --package-lock-only`) Lastly, what's the point of this `package-lock.json` file? Well this file is **automatically generated** for any **operations** where npm modifies either the **node_modules tree, or package.json.** What does this mean? It means `npm` is generating this file, under the hood for you, when you **introduce changes within your Angular project that effect the reproducibility of building your project for others**. In short, it allows others to continue to build and execute your project as you *introduce new important changes to your project*.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Good explanation, Thank you it's more clear for me now.

Comment: Np glad it helped, please accept my answer if you found if helpful

Answer (score 0):

`package-lock.json` describes whole dependency tree that is required by your project. You can see details about it in npm docs.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

> package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where
>   npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It
>   describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent
>   installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of
>   intermediate dependency updates.

Answer (score 0):

@Nathan It's done (y). Thanks again. When I type `yo angular` for client installation I have this after execution :

```
+ karma-jasmine@2.0.1                                                                
+ jasmine-core@3.3.0                                                                 
+ phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16                                                          
+ karma@4.0.0                                                                        
+ karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.4                                                     
added 171 packages from 551 contributors and audited 15612 packages in 57.415s       
found 78 vulnerabilities (35 low, 12 moderate, 30 high, 1 critical)                  
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

What are those types of **vulnerabilities** **==>** **low, moderate, high or critical** ?
Have you an idea please?

Comment: NPM is running a security audit for you based on the packages your project is using. A security audit is an assessment of package dependencies for security vulnerabilities. Security audits help you protect your package’s users by enabling you to find and fix known vulnerabilities in dependencies that could cause data loss, service outages, unauthorized access to sensitive information, or other issues. Most vulnerabilities introduced can be fixed by updating the vulnerable package. Low, moderate, high, and critical refer to the security vulnerability that package exposes.